# Is this a good way to prevent multiple submissions via server-side?

Tags: node.js

Every time the page is updated, I generate a token and place it inside the form, and when the user submits the form, I check if the token has already been used, if it was not used, I store it in an array inside the session.

My question is, do I save the token in cookie (session-express), is it a good practice?

```
    const tokenForm = req.body.tokenForm;

    if(req.session.tokensForm == undefined) {
        req.session.tokensForm = [];
    }

    let tokenFound = false;
    let tmp = req.session.tokensForm;
    for(let i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        if(tmp[i] === tokenForm) {
            tokenFound = true;
            break;
        }
     }

    if (tokenFound == true || tokenForm == undefined || tokenForm === '' || tokenForm === null) {
        req.session.resultPost = 'error';
        return res.redirect('/recuperar/confirmar/');
    }

    if(req.session.tokensForm.length > 100) { // Store up to 100 tokens
        req.session.tokensForm = [];
    }

    req.session.tokensForm.push(tokenForm);
```

Because the cookie can simply be deleted on the client. For more security, should I save to a database, for example?

Comment: You should clarify *why* it's necessary to prevent multiple submissions.

Comment: It is more for learning, I would like to know the best way to do this

Comment: This is required to prevent a record from being counted twice for example